# Wait and Notify problem with many threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a problem with the methods `wait()` and `notify()`. I have three threads, one is called `Management` (which is responsible for managing the others threads) and two called `Worker`, both classes implement `Runnable`. The `Management` submit one task for each `Worker` and keep working. The `Worker`, when recieve a task needs to process the task and wait for other task.

In my `Management`, I have a method called `doWork`, that basically send the tasks to the `Workers` and notify them. All implementation is described below:

WorkerManagement (please, consider constructor and others methods implemented):

```
public class WorkerManagement extends ActiveObject{
    private volatile Map<Worker, Boolean> workers = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    protected void doWork() {
        while(!mustStop()){
            if(getAvailableThreadsSize() != workers.size()){
                continue;
            }
            WorkQueue highestPriorityWorkQueue = workQueues.getHighestPriorityWorkQueue();
            if(highestPriorityWorkQueue == null){
                continue;
            }
            tasks = highestPriorityWorkQueue.pollList();
            for (Map.Entry<Worker, Boolean> entry : workers.entrySet()) {
                Worker worker = entry.getKey();
                worker.updateTask(tasks.poll());
                workers.replace(worker, Boolean.FALSE);
                synchronized (worker) {
                    worker.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private int getAvailableThreadsSize(){
        int availables = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Worker, Boolean> entry : workers.entrySet()) {
            Boolean available = entry.getValue();
            if(available){
                availables++;
            }
        }
        return availables;
    }
}
```

Worker (please, consider constructor and others methods implemented):

```
public class Worker extends ActiveObject{
    private WorkerManagement workerManagement;
    private Task task;

    @Override
    protected void doWork() {
        while (!mustStop()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is Alive:"+Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
            try {
                task.execute();

                workerManagement.setAvailable(this);

                synchronized(this){
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is Alive:"+Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in Worker: " + getName(), ex);
            }
            
        }
    }

}
```

PS: `ActiveObject` is an inner class that implements `Runnable`.

@EDIT: My problem, basically is: One worker is always waiting and the other is always alive. So, when I debug the code on `WorkerManagement` the method `getAvailableThreadsSize` is always returning 1 and the `workers.size()` is returning 2. An example of output of my `doWork` print's is:

```
WorkerThread-1 is Alive:true
WorkerThread-2 is Alive:true
WorkerThread-2 is Alive:true
WorkerThread-2 is Alive:true
WorkerThread-2 is Alive:true
```

Which means that the WorkerThread-2 is always working while WorkerThread-1 is waiting (except the first execution).

Comment: Do you have a question or problem? Please include a description of the current behavior and the desired behavior.

Comment: Normally if you use wait, you check the condition in the synchronized block and you also need to deal with spurious wake-ups (so you put the condition in a loop with a wait)

Comment: Why don't you let the worker and the manager communicate through a blocking queue. No need for dealing with monitors.

Comment: @matt, sorry. I fixed the post and I explained the problem.

Comment: Your tasks are pretty quick, is it possible that by the time the next submit comes in worker thread 2 is available and gets used?

Comment: I think you'll need to turn this into a compilable example because the devil is in the details.

Comment: @matt, my idea is just submit the task (`worker.updateTask(tasks.poll());`) when all threads are waiting. I can't submit when some of them are alive. When I submit the task, the thread that received it needs to start working, and the following iteration on map I will submit another task for other waiting thread, and this thread will start working. What can happen is: I sent the first Task, for Thread-1, it process quickly and start waiting, the next iterationg the Thread-2 will recieve the task and will be notified by worker.notify(). But the thread-1 is already waiting, can it be a problem?

Comment: From your output, thread1 never enters its synchronized block, as it only system.outs once

Comment: @pveentjer, for example: I build and block queue object on `Worker` and then I submit the task. My manager will checks if the size in each block queue is zero and then submit another task for each worker? It can solve my problem, but I think I will be doing it wrong, once I am not doing it in the best way.

Comment: Guys, I got it. Thank you all. Basically, it was an problem because the task (for some inexplicable reason) was null. And then it throws exception and never enter on the block. Sorry for it. I fixed.

Comment: Are you aware that `worker.notify()` will not do _anything at all_ if another thread is not _already_ waiting inside a `worker.wait()` call? When you use `wait()` and `notify()` you need to _guarantee_ that no thread will ever `wait()` for a notification that _previously_ was given. [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) explains how to achieve that guarantee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was becaus the task was `null` and it threw erros before entering on the synchronized block. I fixed it adding and verification on the beggining of the while:

```
if(workUnitToProcess == null){
    synchronized (this) {
        workerManagement.setAvailable(this);
        wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whit this code

```
if (getAvailableThreadsSize() != workers.size()){
    continue;
}
```

if these is a thread running the number of available threads will be workers.size()-1 so only one thread can be activate

try to change to

```
if (getAvailableThreadsSize() >0){
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andrea, thanks for reply. But the map `workers` only contains the classes `Worker` and the method `getAvailableThreadsSize` iterate over the `workers` and check if the values on the map is "true". The map doesn't contain the thread WorkerManagement's object

Comment: For example, the first execution, the method returns 2, because the amount of available thread in that time is 2 (all of them are available)